# Are sock puppet bounties retracted?

Tags: discussion, support, bounties, sock-puppets

A user used sock puppets to grant self bounties. The user's self-upvotes were retracted, and so were bounty rep gains, but the bounties remain visible on answers, and continue to inflate their worth.

Will bounties eventually be retracted? How long does this take?

Comment: Might be "ghost bounties", i.e. showing as usual but actually the rep they gave was taken away and vanished. For example if the account which got the bounty was merged with the one awarding it, or deleted, the bounty exists, but has no real effect.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard The effect is as described in the question. Edited for clarity.

Comment: Well they won't be automatically retracted. If it bothers someone, it's possible to flag the post and ask to retract the bounty.

Comment: In the case of awarded bounties, they will never be invalidated. It would require staff intervention beyond the normal vote invalidation processes which a site moderator could request. Even then, however, it could take a very long time before it gets handled.

Comment: I'll accept these as answers.